# Can someone explain the parameters of OpenCV Stitcher?

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to reduce the calculation time of my stitching algorithm. I got some images which I want to stitch **in a defined order** but it seems like `cv::stitcher.stitch()` function tries to stitch every image with every other image.

I feel like I might find the solution in the parameters of OpenCV Stitcher. If not maybe I have to modify the function or try something else to reduce calculation time. But since I'm pretty much a beginner, I don't know how. I know that using GPU might be a possibility but I just don't get CUDA running on Ubuntu at the moment.

It would be great if you could give me some advice!

Parameters for OpenCV Stitcher module:

```
Stitcher Stitcher::createDefault(bool try_use_gpu) {
Stitcher stitcher;
stitcher.setRegistrationResol(0.6);
stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(0.1);       
stitcher.setCompositingResol(ORIG_RESOL);    
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(1);    
stitcher.setWaveCorrection(true);    
stitcher.setWaveCorrectKind(detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ);    
stitcher.setFeaturesMatcher(new detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher(try_use_gpu));
stitcher.setBundleAdjuster(new detail::BundleAdjusterRay());
```

from *stitcher.cpp*:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp?rev=7244

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html

Comment: The OpenCV [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html) on stitching explains all of the parameters in more detail than could be explained here. If there are any specific questions, change or create a new question

Comment: This doesn't really help me. But thanks anyway. I simply want to know why exactly the opencv stitcher algorithm needs so much longer for stitching ~20 images than stitching 2 images. I feel like it should take 19 times longer but it doesn't, probably because it tries to stitch all images with each other instead of stitching the first one to the second, the second to the third and so on because this is what I need. You know what I mean?

Comment: The algorithm does not scales linearly. The first half (registration stage) grows quadratically.

Comment: @SuvarnaPattayil your link doesn't explain: setRegistrationResol, setSeamEstimationResol, setCompositingResol, setPanoConfidenceThresh and many more... And the new documentation of opencv 3.1 doesn't give any explanation neither.

Comment: @William dead link

Comment: @GPPK your link doesn't explain: setRegistrationResol, setSeamEstimationResol, setCompositingResol, setPanoConfidenceThresh and many more... And the new documentation of opencv 3.1 doesn't give any explanation neither.

Comment: I'd google "opencv stiching doc high level" or dig into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stitch in a defined order but it seems like
> cv::stitcher.stitch() function tries to stitch every image with every
> other image.

[cv::stitcher](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp) does not have a parameter to fulfil your requirement.

However, in the [stitching_detailed.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) sample you have the **--rangewidth** parameter. By setting it to `1`, the algorithm will only consider adjacent image pairs (e.g. for pair 1-2 matches would be computed but not for pair 1-3)